# Power Query Merge Columns to Remove Nulls

Tags: excel, editor, powerquery, m, data-transform

I am new to Power Query Editor, and I am having trouble with one statement.

I need an IF nested statement, where if a Column contains Null, THEN copy the next one over; if that column is Null, copy the next one over.

So far, I have and it's not working.

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Removed Other Columns", 
    "Custom", each 
        if [Date3] = null then [Date2] 
        else if [Date2] = null then [Date1] 
        else if [Date1] = null then [Date3] 
        else [Date3])
```

**What I got**

| Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Custom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/18/2023 | Null | Null | Null |
| 4/18/2023 | 2/18/2023 | Null | 2/18/2023 |
| Null | 2/18/2023 | 1/18/2023 | 1/18/2023 |
| Null | Null | 1/18/2023 | Null |

**What I need**

| Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Custom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/18/2023 | Null | Null | 4/18/2023 |
| 4/18/2023 | 2/18/2023 | Null | 2/18/2023 |
| Null | 2/18/2023 | 1/18/2023 | 1/18/2023 |
| Null | Null | 1/18/2023 | 1/18/2023 |

I tried different IF solutions, and I even used the Conditional Column, but that didn't work. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure why the column feature is not showing it as a column; if you need a better visual, let me know and I will add photos. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the coalesce operator. e.g.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", each [Date3] ?? [Date2] ?? [Date1])
```

https://gorilla.bi/power-query/coalesce/

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want to display markdown tables in your question make sure you have blank lines before and after and that Null is null in PQ.

The logic of your nested if doesn't work: ´if [Date3] = null then [Date2]´ stops the execution of the remaining line.

Try this one instead:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "Custom", 
    each if [Date3] <> null then [Date3] 
         else if [Date2] <> null then [Date2] 
         else [Date1]
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI, there is a coalesce operator to shorten this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each 
        List.Last(List.RemoveNulls({[Date1],[Date2],[Date3]})), type date)
```

If there might be a varying number of `Date` columns, there are other methods also.

***Results***
[image]